# What should I return without pictures?

Tags: java, api, response, javax.ws.rs

I have an API.

```
@GET
@Path("picture")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
Response getPicture(@QueryParam("key") String key);
```

The corresponding service.

```
@Override
public Response getPicture(String key) {
    try{
        byte[] image = service.getPicture(key);
        if (image == null) {

        }
        return Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(image)).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

I try to return null and return Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(null)).build(), but I will get an exception.

What does this method return when image is empty?

Comment: throw e.g. a 404 since the request was **not** ok.

Comment: @luk2302 But I did receive this request, only the requested parameter error.

Comment: @Frank.Dai 404 means "client error: file not found". If the client made a request that points to a file that does not exist, it's correct to return a 404 error.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your patience.